# Delay in DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: swift, dispatch-queue

I have a design like below flow. I need to set delay between 5th and 6th steps for 0.3second. I tried below options but couldn't get any result.

My question is, how can I achieve this?

Note: 13seconds for see the animation.

**Flow**

1. Task Handler // for webService request
2. Closure Handler // for trigger ViewController
3. DispatchQueue.main.async // for Update UI
4. First Animation
5. Second Animation
6. Navigation to next screen

**Test 1**

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 13, repeats: false, block: {})
```

**Test 2**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 13, animations: {
    // nothing should be happened
    self.ivSuccessMark.alpha = 0.99 // for dummy animation diff
}, completion: { (completion) in
    // navigation
})
```

**Test 3**

[perform(_:with:afterDelay:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-perform)

Comment: `UIView.animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` ?

Comment: Use animation completion handler

Answer (score 1):

Try this one I hope it help you(Up to 4 seconds Stop all Action in view)

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(4), execute: {
    // Put your code which should be executed with a delay here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [.repeat, .curveEaseOut, .autoreverse], animations: {
    // animation stuff      
}, completion: { _ in
    // do stuff once animation is complete
})
```

Comment: Tried below code but doesn't work.


UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 13, options:  UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear, animations: {
                                
                            }, completion: { (completion) in
                            })